# Grabbing Primary Key of listed values from sqlite database, dart with flutter

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

Currently my code is grabbing the order of the listed values by how it is indexed and i'm passing it to my raw sql query.   I think i may be going about this the wrong way buy using listviewbuilder, but I want to grab the primary key (from sqlite database) of the clicked on value and pass that to the query on the next page

```
      body: !loading ? new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: sectorList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Card(
              color: Colors.cyan[800],
              elevation: 2.0,
              child: new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("${sectorList[index]}"),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            DocumentPage(id: index),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            );
          },
      ) : CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Comment if you need to see more of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using some type of query like:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> categories =
  await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM tbl_categories order by category_name');
```

This is going to give you a List with each of the categories ordered by name. If the table also contains another column (maybe category_id) that will also be available in the map.

Now each ListTile looks like:

```
          child: new ListTile(
              title: new Text("${categories[index]['category_name']}"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        OtherPage(id: categories[index]['category_id']),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

You display the name, but pass the id to the next page. Assuming then that there's another table with a foreign key of category_id you could:

```
await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM tbl_other WHERE category_id=${widget.id}');
```

This would give you another `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` of all the other things in the relevant category. Use this to build this next page.